# Cannot pay in PayPal sandbox?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, credit-card, express-checkout

I am using Express Checkout, and when testing in sandbox, I used to fill in fake but valid credit card numbers, like those produced by this site: http://www.getcreditcardnumbers.com/

It all worked fine until recently I found that PayPal sandbox no longer accepts these numbers. The page keeps showing **"The card you entered cannot be used for this payment. Please enter a different credit or debit card number."**

[image]

However I did find one card number `4444333322221111` that makes PayPal sanbox show a different error: **"You might already have an account, Please login."** Maybe this means that PayPal does not simply reject any card number.

I also tried creating a test account in Dashboard > Sandbox > Accounts, and use the card number inside the Profile section, but that didn't work either. So how should I test in PayPal sandbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When making a testing in Sandbox for credit card, you must make sure the card number hasn't been used anywhere in PayPal. Use http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/ to get a fresh card number.

Comment: Wow, you're right! Thanks! Now I wonder why I could pass the check for the last few months...

Comment: After a couple of tests, my old way starts to work again. Now I guess it's just paypal broken a few hours ago. But still, thank you for your help and your information!

Answer (score 1):

paypal provides a list of creditcard numbers for testing purposes

https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm

Comment: The new URL of this page is developer.paypal.com/tools/sandbox/card-testing but when I enter any of these numbers, it doesn't accept any saying `You might already have an account, Please login`